# What's the overhead of TPanel over TBevel

Tags: windows, delphi

I'm working on a project where they essentially used TPanel for the only purpose of displaying a bevel (And maybe the design time convenience Panel have over Bevels).

Ok, I know TPanel is heavier than TBevel.  Amongs other things, each TPanel create a user objects, which is a limited resource.

What I would like to know, beyond user objects, what's the overhead of TPanel?  Is it next to non-existent (Especially on modern day machines).

If you were working on such a system, would you suggest :

- Going back and changing all TPanel to TBevel.
- Say "Ok it was bad. Lets not do it again in the future" 
  or
- it's too small a concern and the design time convenience is well
  worth it.

Comment: It might have been a concern in the Windows 3.1 era.

Comment: This question isn't answerable, IMO. Every answer would be dependent on too many unknown variables (for instance, "essentially used" could mean "exclusively" or "sometimes" or "frequently" or "always"). As Andreas said, I wouldn't worry about it. The main concern are the resources TPanel uses (window handle, device context for canvas, etc.), and they're not an issue for the most part anymore under 32 and 64 bit Windows, and the VCL does a pretty good job of only creating them when needed and caching to avoid release and reallocation.

Comment: There are architectural considerations that can make this a complete non-issue, such as creating/freeing forms as needed instead of creating them all at application start up.

Comment: Use whichever you prefer - it makes no discernible difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't know if this design is intentional but, there's a slight navigational behavior difference when controls are grouped together in a window. If the focus is changed by arrow keys, after the one having the last tab order the first control will be focused (down/right), or vice-versa (up/left). IOW the focus will be wrapped in the parent. That's of course if any of the controls do not need the arrow keys.

Regarding the question, as it is already stated in the comments, apart from using up a count in an object pool, there're other resources associated with a window. It will also waste a few CPU cycles. There'll be one more level in the clipping chain or the messaging or keeping one more z-order list etc.. MSDN [puts it as](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (I guess navigational aspect is being referred rather than visual partitioning):

> For best performance, an application that needs to logically divide its main window should do so in the window procedure of the main window rather than by using child windows.

Nevertheless, as again already stated in the comments, most probably, no one will be able to tell the performance or resource difference caused by a few panels..

Comment: I'd like to add : Probably the most important difference was related to the consumption of desktop heap memory. On the default settings of WinXP, I was routinely running out of resources. In the post WinXP versions, the default for desktop heap memory is at least 4 times what it was (more in Win64). See : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/126962/en-us

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is choice #3, so if that's the project's design approach, *don't change it.*